# Performing Repeated filtering in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I want to get the names of people who work in bmw and use these names as filter to find and return the documnents containing the field "car". So the end result must be the last two documents given in this example.

```
[
    {"_id": "235", "name": "indu", "dob": "31/4/15", "company": "bmw"},
    {"_id": "236", "name": "prith", "dob": "01/4/98", "company": "bmw"},
    {"_id": "237", "name": "rames", "dob": "07/4/00", "company": "renault"},
    {"_id": "238", "name": "indu", "salary": "10,000", "car": "yes", "married": "yes"},
    {"_id": "239", "name": "prith", "salary": "80,000", "car": "yes", "children": "no"}
]
```

I appreciate your help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

```
names = db.collection.distinct{"name", {"company": "bmw"})
db.collection.find({"car": {"$exists": true}, "name": {"$in": names}})
```

You can also do it in 1 aggregation call although I would not recommend it as It's less efficient.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
       "$match": {
           "company": "bmw"
       }   
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "this_collection",
            localField: "name",
            foreignField: "name",
            as: "roots"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$roots"
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$roots"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "car": {"$exists": true}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Nice solution.. Solved my problem.. Thank you Tom